# How to simplify an angular reactive form validation boilerplate

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have this sort of form:

```
 this.form = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        // more controls here
      }
    );
```

Html:

```
    <form  class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
        <div
          class="form__control form-control"
          [class.form-control--valid]="vm.name.valid && (vm.name.dirty || vm.name.touched)"
          [class.form-control--invalid]="vm.name.invalid && (vm.name.dirty || vm.name.touched)">
          <label for="form_name" class="form-control__label">Your name</label>
          <div class="form-control__input-wrapper form-control__input-wrapper--marked">
            <input type="text" class="form-control__input" id="form_name" name="name" formControlName="name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-control__feedback" *ngIf="vm.name.errors && (vm.name.dirty || vm.name.touched)">
            <p *ngIf="vm.name.errors.required">First name is required</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- more controls here-->
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]='!form.valid'>Submit</button>
      </form>
```

`vm` is equal to `this.form.controls;`

It seems to me that the html contains to much code related to form validation.

I wonder if it is possible to reduce the amount of markup code to avoid writing all that `vm.name.invalid && (vm.name.dirty || vm.name.touched`.

Also I believe things like that could be simplified, it is a lot of boilerplate to:

```
[class.form-control--valid]="vm.name.valid && (vm.name.dirty || vm.name.touched)"
[class.form-control--invalid]="vm.name.invalid && (vm.name.dirty || vm.name.touched)"
```

Comment: By having a generic component, you only have to write all that logic once. What you can do is have a formControl component that takes the control as an Input and then manage all of the validations from there. Label and input as content projection so its easily reusable

Comment: You could also move some logic into getters you have defined in the component file like
get IsNameValid() {
 vm.name.invalid && (vm.name.dirty || vm.name.touched; }

And then use that in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular yet add different class if valid or touched. See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes)

Based on it, I suggest these are the class you can add to your divs (*)

As always we can improve a "tag" sometimes it's util use a directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[errorClass]'
})
export class ErrorClassDirective {
  @ContentChild(NgControl) control:NgControl;
  @HostBinding('class') get class()
  {
    if (!this.control)
      return null

    let className=this.control.invalid?'ng-invalid ':'ng-valid '
    className+=this.control.touched?'ng-touched ': 'ng-untouched'
    className+=this.control.dirty?'ng-dirty ': 'ng-pristine'
    return className;
  }
}
```

Then we can use some like

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div errorClass>
    <label>Control</label>
    <input formControlName="control" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Now we can play with .css

e.g.

```
/*Some class to style the inputs and labels*/
label {
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
}
input {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

input:focus {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #86b7fe;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
}

/*Here style the "div"*/
.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(input),
.ng-invalid.ng-dirty:not(input) {
  color: red;
}

/*Style the input invalid*/
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched,
input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
  border-color: red;
  outline: none;
}
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:focus,
input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty:focus {
  border-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xyhw69?file=src%2Fapp%2Ferror-class.directive.ts)

(*) with the new selector [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) you needn't any directive, We can simply use a class in the way

```
div:has(input.ng-invalid.ng-touched)
{
  color:red
}
```

Unfortunaly this selector is not ready for some navigator (Firefox need User must explicitly enable this feature)